# Running observer after "Billing Information" in Magento onepage checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, observers

I am trying to run an observer directly after the user has clicked 'submit' on the 'Billing Information' on the onepage checkout in Magento.

Here is the code I have in my module xml but having no joy at the moment

```
       <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling>
            <observers>
                <ss_raptor_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>SS_Raptor_Model_Raptor_Observer</class>
                    <method>afterBillingMethod</method>
                </ss_raptor_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling>
     </events>
```

I am using magento 1.7 - can anyone confirm what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This worked - found it via IRC

```
controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling
```

Why is it capital B though... (sigh)

Comment: The capital "B" comes from the name of the controller method: `saveBillingAction` which ends up being in the URL (`.../onepage/saveBilling`), which is then taken by Magento to create a dynamic controller event - `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below. Replace with your NameSpace and ModuleName

```
<events>
     <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling>
     <observers>
     <NameSpace_YourModule_Model_Observer>
     <type>singleton</type>
     <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
     <method>afterBillingMethod</method>
     </NameSpace_YourModule_Model_Observer>
     </observers>
     </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling> 
</events>
```

Comment: Hi - I have another observer which is exactly the same, except it uses a different observer name called 'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method'
and this works fine. So I am leading to believe I have mixed up 'controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling' and need a different observer to replace it.

Comment: I assume `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method` is your event

Comment: yeh that is correct - that is the name of the observer event on the first line

Answer (score 0):

just in case if, like me, you needed to run an observer after the billing address is SAVED (means quote updated), use the following event:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_savebilling
```

And the following in case shipping address step is updated:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveshipping
```

Maybe that still could helps.